# Django auth customing

Tags: django

I want to custom the django auth app, since the default auth app can not do everything our project need. Then I figure it out on my own by checking the django document at here. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#a-full-example. I tried to do that example exactly. Finally, I added AUTH_USER_MODEL = "intelic_auth.MyUser" setting in my settings.py. But I got this error below when I tried to run "python manage.py syncdb". I don't know why. I would be very appreciated if someone can help me figure it out.

```
CommandError: One or more models did not validate:

helpdesk.ticket: 'assigned_to' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

helpdesk.followup: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

helpdesk.savedsearch: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

helpdesk.usersettings: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.

helpdesk.ticketcc: 'user' defines a relation with the model 'auth.User', which has been swapped out. Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I passed through that problem some days ago. I was trying to sub-class USer model with a customized one that added some more fields.

Instead of inherit from User, I changed to AbstractUser and everything worked ok

Answer (score 0):

Ensure you followed [this part](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) of the doc.

Roughly speaking, it says that you need to change the way you reference your users in FKs.

**The Right way to do it when you use customized user:** (example of the documentation)

```
class Article(models.Model):
    author = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL)
```

Plus, if you read the errors you have, it seems clear enough : `Update the relation to point at settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL`. As you have this errors 5 times, you need to do this changes in 5 places in your models.py file.